# How to find the maximum count using mysql?

Tags: mysql

Please let me know what is wrong with the below command

```
mysql> select max(count(*)) from emp1 group by name;
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

Comment: I suppose that there are several lines in the table where `name` has the same value. He wants to find the `name` with the largest number of lines.

Comment: Are you trying to count the `name` and then only return the highest count?

Comment: You cannot aggregate an aggregate within the same scope

Answer (score 36):

Try:

```
SELECT NAME, 
       COUNT(*) as c 
FROM table 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: matsko approved Halley's edit, which added `NAME, ` to the select. However, if the goal is to simply get back the scalar value of the maximum count, this change was not needed. In that case, can simply use the original code: `SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 26):

From the supplied code I understand that you wish to select the highest number of employees that share the same name.

> The problem with your query is that you are trying to apply more than one level of aggregation in a single scope.

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(Total) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM emp1 GROUP BY name) AS Results
```

...or this:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) FROM emp1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Both queries return the same result, but their implementations are different.

Use whichever is the fastest for you or whichever you prefer.

Comment: Unless we're being particularly pedantic, I think this provides an answer - although order by limit would be more usual

Comment: The subquery is more canonical, as the order by limit is more a hack, so you see both in the wild. The first is most often written by programmers having formal education in data persistence, but we really can see it.

Answer (score 6):

I'd to the following (assuming I understand correctly what you want):

```
select c from
(
    select count(*) as c, name from emp1 group by name
) tmp
order by c desc limit 1
```

This selects the largest count from all counts by name. For example, if your table contains

```
Name
-----------------------
Test
Test
Hello
World
World
World
```

The inner select would create a "table" with this data

```
c         Name
----------------------
2         Test
1         Hello
3         World
```

The outer select would order this by `c` descending and select the first entry, which is `3`.

This can be shortened to

```
select count(*) c from emp1 group by name order by c desc limit 1
```

Comment: Obviously, the outer query's not required here. ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1 would do just as well

Answer (score 6):

You are asking "what is wrong with your statement".  This is your statement:

```
select max(count(*))
from emp1
group by name;
```

*I* understand what you mean.  But a SQL Compiler does not.  The reason is simple.  A given `select` can have only one `group by` clause.  And your query is asking for two of them.  The first is the `group by` name.  The second is an aggregation on all those results.

The proper way to write your query (as you seem to intend) is using a subquery:

```
select max(cnt)
from (select count(*) as cnt
      from emp1
      group by name
     ) t
```

This is a perfectly reasonable solution that only uses standard SQL.  Other answers have proposed the solution using the `limit` clause, which may be a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You must select `name` to group by it, then use `max()` on the result of that as a subquery:

```
select max(count)
from (
  select
    name,
    count(*) as count
  from emp1
  group by name) x
```

I have formatted the query so you can see what's happening, rather than put it all on one line as you showed it. Btw the "x" at he fnf is a required alias for the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  MAX(name_count)
FROM
        (
        SELECT  name
                ,count(*) as name_count
        FROM    emp1 
        GROUP BY
                name
        )
```

Comment: Is there a way to also select the name in the outermost SELECT statement? So if you wanted to know which name group was the one with the MAX(name_count)?

Answer (score 0):

In case the data happened to have multi occurrences for the max value the **LIMIT 1** will not answer the question.
In order to illustrate this, I used the **[WOLRD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html)** database sample from **MySQL** to answer this question.

> Q) Return the list of the country(ies) that has the highest number of languages.

**FIVE** countries fit to have the same number of languages **which is 12** namely

1. Canada
2. China
3. India
4. Russia
5. USA

Firstly, we need to create a **VIEW** to hold the max value (in this case is 12)

```
CREATE VIEW abc AS SELECT count(countrycode) AS total FROM 
countrylanguage GROUP BY countrycode 
ORDER BY COUNT(countrycode) DESC limit 1;
```

then use the **view** in the **SELECT** statement below:

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(country.`name`) FROM country JOIN    
countrylanguage ON country.`code` = countrylanguage.countrycode 
GROUP BY country.`name` 
HAVING COUNT(country.`name`) = (SELECT total FROM abc) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't  need max here i think you want know the employee count

then use just count()
like this

```
select count(*) from emp1
```

but here another example for use max with count for example we need to know most author have many books

```
SELECT  book_author.`author_id`
,  COUNT(book_author.`book_id`)  AS books_count
 FROM book_author
GROUP BY book_author.`author_id`
HAVING   COUNT(book_author.`book_id`)=(SELECT MAX(t1.book_count) 
 FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(book_author.`book_id`)  AS book_count 
FROM  book_author
GROUP BY book_author.`author_id` )t1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 ***Example: 1***
 SELECT *
 FROM customer
 WHERE customer.ID IN
      (SELECT customer_id
         FROM (SELECT customer_id, MAX(cust_count)
                 FROM (SELECT customer_id,
                              COUNT(customer_id)
                                 AS cust_count
                         FROM `order`
                       GROUP BY customer_id) AS cust_count_tbl) AS cust_tbl);


***Example -2*** 

SELECT *
      FROM    customer
   LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT customer_id, COUNT(customer_id) AS cc
         FROM `order`
       GROUP BY customer_id
       ORDER BY cc DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS kk
   ON customer.ID = kk.customer_id
   WHERE kk.customer_id = customer.ID;
```